# How to run/invoke Instrumented Tests from within Android App code (MainActivity)

Tags: android, ui-automation, instrumented-test

In the current arrangement, on Android, Instrumented Tests can be invoked by following approaches:

1. From within Android Studio -> Right click on the class saved under "androidTest"
2. Fire command `adb shell am instrument -w com.example.testing/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` on CMD prompt.

But **mine is unique requirement**. As per my requirement, I would like to Run/Invoke these test cases (written inside classes saved under androidTest) from UI of the App code itself i.e. when user clicks on a button presented on the UI, the respective test case(s) get executed.

Following is the code written in "ExampleInstrumentedTest" saved under "androidTest" Folder.

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.uiautomator.UiDevice

import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

import org.junit.Assert.*

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * See [testing documentation](http://d.android.com/tools/testing).
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    fun testCaseForButton1() {
        val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        //Filler step
        assertEquals("com.example.myapplication", appContext.packageName)
    }

    @Test
    fun testCaseForButton2() {
        val device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
        //Filler step
        assertEquals("com.sec.android.app.launcher", device.launcherPackageName)
    }
}
```

Code in MainActivity():

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonRunTest1)
            .setOnClickListener {
                //Invoke testCaseForButton1
            }

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonRunTest2)
            .setOnClickListener {
                //Invoke testCaseForButton2
            }
    }
```

I read somewhere that "instrumented" tests can not be called/triggered from within App code. Also tried but failed with error "No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation"

Request help with code to be written inside the "OnClickListener".

Tried couple of approaches:

```
// Code to execute when the button is clicked
fun startTest(){
   val packageName = "com.example.myapplication"
   val testRunnerClass = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   val command = "am instrument -w $packageName/$testRunnerClass"
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
}
```

```
// Code to execute when the button is clicked
fun startTest(){
   val instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
   val paramTypes = arrayOf(ComponentName::class.java, Bundle::class.java)
   val method = instrumentation.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("startInstrumentation", *paramTypes)
}
```

My build.gradle:

```
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.5.0'
}
```

But nothing works. Ideally, they should invoke respective instrumented test cases.

Answer (score 0):

From the two approaches you showed only the first is suitable since access to Instrumented test API like InstrumentationRegistry is only available within an instrumentation test class (AFAIK)... For the first one to work you will need root access... You can use a method like this to execute commands

```
public static int ExecCommand(String command, boolean su) {
    try {
        if (su) {
            command = "su -c " + command;
        }
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        return process.exitValue();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```